# AWS Kinesis streaming application failed to sink data to Redis

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am using AWS Kinesis Streaming Application to process streaming data.

The application is running but I found nothing was sank to my Redis. Related code:

```
public class SpyProcessor {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(SpyProcessor.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        // Process logic
         ......
        

        //Redis sink
        FlinkJedisPoolConfig conf = new FlinkJedisPoolConfig.Builder().setHost("my-redis-host").setPort(6379).build();

        aggStream.addSink(new RedisSink<>(conf, new RedisSinkExample()));
        log.info("Redis sink added");
        env.execute("Kinesis Data Analytics Flink Application with  Session Window and Aggregate Function");



public class RedisSinkExample implements RedisMapper<SpyViewCount> {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(RedisSinkExample.class);

//    private Jedis jedis;

    @Override
    public RedisCommandDescription getCommandDescription() {
        return new RedisCommandDescription(RedisCommand.SET, null);
    }

    @Override
    public String getKeyFromData(SpyViewCount spyViewCount) {
        log.info("sinking key: " + spyViewCount.getUserId() + "_" + spyViewCount.getElement());
        return spyViewCount.getUserId() + "_" + spyViewCount.getElement();
    }

    @Override
    public String getValueFromData(SpyViewCount spyViewCount) {
        log.info("sinking value: " + spyViewCount.getCount());
        return spyViewCount.getCount().toString();
    }
}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SpyViewCount {
    private String userId;
    private Long element;
    private Long count;
    private Long windowEnd;
}
```

My Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.11</java.version>
        <kda.version>2.0.0</kda.version>
        <kda.runtime.version>1.2.0</kda.runtime.version>
        <flink.version>1.15.2</flink.version>
        <seel-common-version>1.1.54</seel-common-version>
        <kinesis.analytics.flink.version>2.0.0</kinesis.analytics.flink.version>
        <kinesis.analytics.runtime.version>1.2.0</kinesis.analytics.runtime.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.903</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-redis_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kinesis</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flink-shaded-guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${kinesis.analytics.runtime.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-flink</artifactId>
            <version>${kinesis.analytics.flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-logs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.seel</groupId>
            <artifactId>merchant-service-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.80</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.seel</groupId>
            <artifactId>seel-common</artifactId>
            <version>${seel-common-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${kda.runtime.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-flink</artifactId>
            <version>${kda.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>instant-variable</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
                                    <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>
                                        com.seel.quasi.spy.SpyProcessor
                                    </mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


        <finalName>spy_${maven.build.timestamp}</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

I can see in Cloudwatch Logs that the application is processing streaming data. However, no a single data sank to my redis server.

Hope someone can help..

Data successfully sink to redis server